# MPI C Tree Structured Global Sum

Tags: c, tree, sum, mpi

How do I pair processes using MPI in C? It's a tree structured approach. Process 0 should be adding from all of the other even processes, which they are paired with. I only need it to work for powers of 2.

Should I be using MPI_Reduce instead of MPI Send/Receive? If so, why?

My program doesn't seem to get past for loop inside the first if statement. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(void){
  int sum, comm_sz, my_rank, i, next, value;
  int divisor = 2;
  int core_difference = 1;

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  srandom((unsigned)time(NULL) + my_rank);
  value = random() % 10;

      //process should recieve and add
      if (my_rank % divisor == 0){

          printf("IF----");

          printf("Process %d generates: %d\n", my_rank, value);

          for (i = 0; i < comm_sz; i++)
          {
              MPI_Recv(&value, 1, MPI_INT, i, my_rank , MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
               sum += value;  
               printf("Current Sum=: %d\n", sum);

          }

          printf("The NEW divisor is:%d\n", divisor);
          divisor *= 2;
          core_difference *= 2;

      }

      //sending the random value - no calculation
      else if (my_rank % divisor == core_difference){
          printf("ELSE----");
          printf("Process %d generates: %d\n", my_rank, value);
          MPI_Send(&value, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      }
      else
         if (my_rank==0)
            printf("Sum=: %d\n", sum);

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you delete your previous, nearly identical question to create this one? That behavior is frowned upon on SO. The right thing to do is edit your question to make it better.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would just be easier to re-write the entire question. Should i undelete the old question?

Comment: At this point the damage is done. You've already created a new one so there's no point in going back.

Comment: do you guys have any insight on my question? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just haven't had time to paste your code into a terminal yet. Can only do so much from the iPhone app :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your processes are all receiving from themselves. If I add a print statement before each send and receive with the processes involved in the operation, here's the output:

```
$ mpiexec -n 8 ./a.out
IF----Process 0 generates: 5
ELSE----Process 1 generates: 1
ELSE----Process 3 generates: 1
IF----Process 4 generates: 9
ELSE----Process 5 generates: 7
IF----Process 6 generates: 2
ELSE----Process 7 generates: 0
0 RECV FROM 0
1 SEND TO 0
3 SEND TO 0
4 RECV FROM 0
5 SEND TO 0
6 RECV FROM 0
7 SEND TO 0
IF----Process 2 generates: 7
2 RECV FROM 0
1 SEND TO 0 DONE
3 SEND TO 0 DONE
5 SEND TO 0 DONE
7 SEND TO 0 DONE
```

Obviously, everyone is hanging while waiting for rank 0, including rank 0. If you want to send to yourself, you'll need to use either `MPI_Sendrecv` to do both the send and receive at the same time or use nonblocking sends and receives (`MPI_Isend`/`MPI_Irecv`).

As you said, another option would be to use collectives, but if you do that, you'll need to create new subcommunicators. Collectives require all processes in the communicator to participate. You can't pick just a subset.